# Помогите написать самый простой парсер на AngleSharp

Tags: c#, html, парсер, anglesharp

Как например изъять заголовок на сайте [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Царство_(биология)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)), спрашиваю исключительно для саморазвития, можно пожалуйста с комментариями, спасибо

Сейчас продвинулся только так :

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var doc = parser.Parse("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Царство_(биология)");
var div = doc.QuerySelector(); // тут не понимаю как и что писать в скобках
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите какая у вас конкретно проблема с этим, что вы пытались и что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: если честно не смог найти ни одного учебника по AngleSharp, все что я нашел - это ответ на вопрос по парсингу всех href со страницы, и тот код не понял

Comment: IHtmlDocument angle = new HtmlParser(html).Parse();
foreach (IElement element in angle.QuerySelectorAll("h3.r a"))
    Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("href"));

Answer (score 5):

[image: Иллюстрация работы примера]

Для сбора данных создадим такой класс

```
public class WikiInfo
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> Paragraphs { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Images { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Такой класс парсера

```
class Parser
{
    public async Task<WikiInfo> GetWiki()
    {
        // конфигурация
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        // 
        var address = "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)";
        // асинхронно загружаем страницу
        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);


        WikiInfo result = new WikiInfo();

        //--Заголовок
        var cellSelector = @"h1#section_0";
        var cell = document.QuerySelector(cellSelector);
        result.Header = cell.TextContent;

        //--Картинки
        foreach (var image in document.Images)
        {
            result.Images.Add(image.Source);
        }

        //--Параграфы
        cellSelector = @"main#content p";
        var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
        var pars = cells.Select(m => m.TextContent);
        result.Paragraphs = new List<string>(pars);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==ConsoleApp2==");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var parser = new Parser();
        var ress = parser.GetWiki().Result;

        Console.WriteLine($"Заголовок статьи: {ress.Header}");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 20));

        Console.WriteLine("Ссылки на картинки:");
        foreach (var item in ress.Images)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 20));
        Console.WriteLine("Параграфы статьи:");
        foreach (var item in ress.Paragraphs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```