# HtmlAgilityPack Как спарсить данные и положить их в коллекцию?

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Использую код с [сайта](https://lsreg.ru/parsing-sajtov-na-c/), он работает и с ним все хорошо.
Но я не понимаю принципа

```
//создаем переменную и кладем в нее сразу через фунекцию код страницы 
var pageContent = LoadPage(@"https://www.noob-club.ru/");
//Создаем объект класса
var document = new HtmlDocument();
//Используем метод класса и отправляем в него код страницы 
document.LoadHtml(pageContent);

//дальше не совсем понятно
//Создаем коллекцию и кладем в не то что спарсили?
HtmlNodeCollection links = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[4]/span[1]/h1/a");
foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", link.InnerText, link.GetAttributeValue("href", "")); 

    //Этот код не сработает так как я незнаю что делает "link.InnerText, link.GetAttributeValue("href", "")" и не редактировал их.

    //Если я попытаюсь вывести содержимое коллекции
     HtmlNodeCollection links = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//h2/a");
     Console.WriteLine(links[1]);
    //то получу
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
```

Как мне просто спарсить данные одним xpath и положить их в коллекцию? 
Сайт который в коде просто для примера.

Comment: Вы не понимаете что такое XPaht как минимум. Не стоит его копировать из всяких генераторов (браузеров), думайте что пишете. Сейчас вы пишете "Слушай, а возьми ка мне из документа `html`, в нем возьми `body`, там возьми 5-й `div`..."  Что произойдет например, если нужный контент будет в `div` под номером 10? Или вовсе он перейдет куда то в другое место (в другой `div` например)? Вам нужно искать что-то уникальное в этой всей каше, например `Id` или `class` и уже по ним искать контент.

Comment: Например если вы напишете `"//td[@class='content']/div[@class='entry first']"`, то получите "ноды" всех новостей сайта, дальше вам по полученному результату нужно будет пройтись циклом и распарсить каждую "ноду", например получение заголовка - `"./span[@class="entry-header"]"` и у полученной "ноды" вызываете `InnerText`. Теперь сами `InnerText` и `GetAttributeValue()` - первое выдаст вам текст, который находится в этом месте, без `html`, а второе выдаст значение какого либо атрибута (в вашем коде это `href` у ссылки).

Comment: Вот я пытаюсь спарсить `https://www.google.com/search?q=free+proxy+list`
Вот код `HtmlNodeCollection links = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class,'g')]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]");
foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", link.InnerText, link.GetAttributeValue("href","")); `
Я проверял xpath в 3х разных программах и он находит ссылки, а тут почему то ошибка.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ef9NHv

Comment: Надо убрать tbody из XPath и тогда ноду(ы) находит, я проверял. Но, через xpath крайне неудобно работать, и потому лучше использовать css селекторы и AngleSharp, пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1008091/222542) ну и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049162/222542).

Comment: @User12351259599491 В коде, что вы скинули, посмотрите что у вас находится в `pageContent`, посмотрите, похожа ли та страница, что отдает вам гугл на ту, что он выдает в браузере. Я вам скажу, что нет.